# creating abbreviations for commonly used paths

Tags: shell, directory, alias

I  was wondering whether it is possible to create abbreviations that can be used in terminal. I know about `alias` command, but am not sure whether that can be used for what I am looking for.

Example: Say I often need to copy stuff from folder `~/Dropbox/thisfolder`. I know that I can create a shortcut to switch to this folder by creating an alias, such as,

```
alias tf="cd ~/Dropbox/thisfolder"
```

However, if I do

```
alias justpath="~/Dropbox/thisfolder"
```

then, I cannot use commands such as `cp justpath/blahfile ./`. Is it possible to do something like this using some other way to abbreviate the path `~/Dropbox/thisfolder`?

Comment: Use a variable, e.g. `justpath=~/Dropbox/thisfolder` then `cp $justpath...`

Comment: I use symlinks, which I collect in a "shallow" easily accessible directory, like `~/Desktop`.  This way the short paths are shell-agnostic.  The only caveat is to be careful running recursive commands on the symlink dir (tell them to not follow symlinks).

Comment: This depends a lot on your shell; there are several good ways in `zsh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any shell, you can define a variable.

```
justpath=~/Dropbox/thisfolder
```

(Note: no quotes here, otherwise the `~` wouldn't be expanded.) Prefix it with a `$` to use it:

```
cp $justpath/blahfile .
```

Note that unless you're using zsh, if the value contains whitespace or wildcards `*?\[`, you need to put double quotes around the variable expansion when you use it.

```
justpath=~/'Dropbox/that folder'
cp "$justpath/blahfile" .
```

Zsh has (as it often does) better facilities. You can define [named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories) accessed with the syntax `~foo`, generalizing the case where `foo` is a user name and `~foo` is this user's home directory.

```
alias -d justpath=~/Dropbox/thisfolder
cp ~justpath/blahfile .
```

And for more complex cases, zsh offers [dynamic named directories](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Dynamic-named-directories).

Comment: Strictly speaking that's not for _any_ shell.
In `csh` the variables are set with the `set` command.

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin “Shell” in the unix world today (as opposed to 20 years ago) usually means Bourne-style shell by default. Csh, fish, psh, non-command-line shells and so on aren't included.

Comment: I agree, csh is mostly terrible, but "default" and "any" are quite different things anyway.