# Change command name in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating abbreviations for commonly used paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38903/creating-abbreviations-for-commonly-used-paths)

I'm new to the Linux platform. Is there any way to rename the commands available in Linux.

For example, I use the `clear` command a lot and instead of typing it every time I want to rename it as just `c`. Is this possible ?

Comment: Note that **it's usually better to learn the proper command names** (and relevant parameters) **first.** Otherwise, you will be thoroughly confused when using systems that do not have your customizations. That is a trap a lot of people who get used to having an alias `rm` to `rm -i` fall into, and it can be more or less dangerous depending on the exact commands involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an alias, as you have figured that out, or just use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear the screen contents.

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

```
alias c="clear"
```

Now pressing <kbd>c</kbd> instead of typing `clear` clears the screen.

Comment: Ctrl-l works as well...

Comment: Don't forget to add this line to your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` if the former is quite empty, depends on your distribution) to still have the setting after your next login