# how to change `rm` to as a command like `mv ~/ .trash`

Tags: rename, alias, rm

I like to use rm 
but I often made mistakes so that I remove something mistakenly
so I want to make somthing like `mv .trash`

so that

```
 rm file
```

is equal to

```
 mv file ~/.trash
```

besides, I also want to periodically empty the ~/.trash folder
then if I have made rm as `mv`, how to empty the ~/.trash folder

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make a simple script called for example `move_to_trash.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv "$@" ~/.trash
```

and then, add to your shell configuration file (for example, `~/.bashrc`) :

```
alias rm <path to script>/move_to_trash.sh
```

To empty your trash periodically, you can configure a cronjob. Look at this tutorial for examples: http://www.ubuntututorials.com/use-crontab-ubuntu/.

Comment: But you should in fact use a program like `trash-cli` instead of hacking `rm`.

Comment: Using `$*` in a shell script is almost always wrong - it fails, it the filename contains whitespace or shell globbing characters. Use `"$@"` instead.

Comment: oops, yes you're right. gonna edit that right now

Comment: Why do you suggest shadow-aliasing `rm` when you know it is not recommended? You should change your answer, and not put that in a comment (since it is important). I know **you** know it, but for the OP - @misteryes - check out [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66934/why-is-aliasing-over-standard-commands-not-recommended).

Comment: I use "answer" to answer the question which is "How do I make `rm file` equal to `mv file ~/.trash`?" and "comment" to give additional information. Of course, this should not be done but from a technical point of view, it's possible and I show how.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an alias. For example: `alias rm 'mv \!* ~/.trash'`

However, aliasing built-in commands can cause problems. So rather than aliasing `rm`, I'd call the alias `del` instead, that way your regular `rm` is still available to you.

Comment: can you explain `\!*` a bit? thanks

Comment: does not work for me on the \!*