# change rm alias to mv

Tags: alias, rm, mv

Reference: [how to change `rm` to as a command like `mv ~/ .trash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74213/how-to-change-rm-to-as-a-command-like-mv-trash/74215#74215)

I would like to implement recycle bin utility in UNIX since UNIX not has one.

In `.bashrc` file I change alias `rm='move.sh"`

as per above Reference guide I have written function in my move.sh script

Script : move.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh
    
 TRASH=<trash directory path>
    
 move()
 {
   mv "$@" $TRASH;  
 }
 move
```

when I run I am getting below error. Can some one please help what's wrong I am doing?

> mv: Insufficient arguments (1)
> Usage: mv [-f] [-i] f1 f2
> mv [-f] [-i] f1 ... fn d1
> mv [-f] [-i] d1 d2

Comment: Trash does not work like that. The issue is obvious if you consider trashing files `foo/hello.c` and `bar/hello.c`. Either (a) you need to create the directory trees, or (b) you have one `hello.c` in your trash but you cannot know whether it came from `foo` or `bar`. A decent Trash will preserve two or more distinct versions of `hello.c` trashed at different times, even from the same directory. It needs to store metadata to be able to untrash files, much like an archive.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli. It's in the main Arch repo (as `trash-cli`), not sure about other distros.

Comment: While my answer addressed "What's wrong with the code?", this seems to more accurately satisfy "I want a trash function in Linux". I encourage the OP to look into `trash-cli` once the script is fixed. Writing your own, *proper* trash script is a bit more work than moving a file to a designated folder. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if that is the entirety of your script, you don't need to first make a function. Simply write:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TRASH=<trash directory path>
echo "$TRASH"
mv "$@" "$TRASH"
```

But to answer what is wrong with your script, the most obvious error is that you are not passing any arguments to your function. In other words, the last line in your script should also get the script arguments passed to it. `move` should become `move "$@"`.

Other than that, remember to always quote your variables if you don't have an explicit reason not to.

---

As you seem to want this in `.bashrc`, just create the function straight in there:

```bsh
cat <<'EOF' | tee -a "$HOME/.bashrc"
trash(){ local t="/my/trash/path"; [[ -n "$*" ]] && echo "$t" && mv "$@" "$t" ;}
EOF
```

I strongly suggest not over-writing the standard `rm` command, which is why I made it `trash` in my example

Comment: Actually my preferred method usually, but I find "no output" to confuse the less experienced, so picked tee this time. Same result regardless.

Comment: +1.  Also... RE: quoting variables unless you have a specific reason not to, the same applies to script args like $1, $2, $@, and $*. Parameter expansion is prone to the same kinds of errors and problems as variable expansion.   Your trash function should quote $* too, otherwise it will break if there's more than one arg - e.g.  `[[ -n "$*" ]]`.      BTW, to demonstrate: run `[[ -n 1 2 3 ]] && echo true` in a bash terminal.  Note the errors.  Then run `[[ -n "1 2 3" ]] && echo true`.  `-n` only takes one arg.

Comment: BTW, this would be worth another +1 by itself, if it were possible: I also agree on not over-writing standard `rm`, certainly not without writing a complex function capable of handling all of `rm`'s options, and probably not even then.  A separate `trash` function is better.

Comment: for your first comment, it has been edited!

Comment: @KaffeMyers - as per you suggested while calling move function added move "$@"  solve the issue. Thanks you for your help!